# jQuery UI resizable: fixed height when using east handle alone

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, resize, css-tables

I created a 'CSS Div Table' using the code below.
I would like to make the columns resizable using the JQuery UI Resizable plugin.

This works fine, however as soon as the text in the column doesn't fit anymore, it will wrap the line which will make my row heigher. I would like to hide the text that doesn't fit in the cell.

Is this posible using the DIV's as table cells? Or is there some kind of work around / better method?

See the jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dd05gaad/).

**HTML**

```js
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell resize">If i make this colums smaller i this row to remain it's hight</div>
        <div class="cell">I tried playing arround with</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell resize">and just break the text (making it unvisible)</div>
        <div class="cell ">white-space (nowrap) and some overflow values</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell resize"></div>
        <div class="cell">but the no wrap makes the drag stop on the longest line</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.table {
 display: table;
 width: 100%;
}

.row {
 display: table-row;
}

.cell {
 padding: 3px;
 display: table-cell; 
 border-right: 1px solid #000;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
 /*overflow: invisible;
 white-space: nowrap;*/
}
```

**JQUERY**

```js
$(function () {
    $('.resize').resizable({
        handles: 'e'
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you try using max-height and max-width css properties?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
.cell {
 padding: 3px;
 display: table-cell; 
 border-right: 1px solid #000;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
 overflow: hidden;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: This has the same effect. The white-space: nowrap seems to stop the resizable plugin from making the cell smaller than the tekst inside, and leaving it out wraps the text to the next line which makes the cell higher.